# ffmpeg How to reduce the processing speed of ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video with fps=30, But when I run the command, I see the following:

```
frame=32  fps=62  q=-1.0  Lsize=N/A  time=00:00:01.27  bitrate=N/A
```

That's the processing speed i.e. 62 frames processed per second.

But I want to reduce it to fps = 40 or fps = 50.

What I have to do

Comment: What's your full command?

Comment: this is full my command: Thanks Mulvya

Comment: ffmpeg -y -i "video1.mp4" -i "video2.mp4" -af  "[0:a]atempo=1.2" -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS/1.2[v2],[1:v][v2]overlay=30:30"  -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 32 -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 1400k -profile:v main -level 3.1 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100  -shortest -preset superfast "Outputvideo.mp4"

Comment: Change preset to fast or medium.

Comment: Thank Mulvya. how about flag -re ? but flag -re will Read input at native frame rate(fps~30) but i want fps=40 ~50. What other flags to limit the speed of reading the input?
Thanks Again

Comment: I found that the -readrate _[speed]_  flag does exactly that. "Its value is a floating-point positive number which represents the maximum duration of media, in seconds, that should be ingested in one second of wallclock time." E.g. -readrate 1.34 if native fps is 30 and you want to read about 40 fps.